# Refinerycms can't call my own controller route,actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

First i created refinerycms application,
in side my application i can't call my own controller route,actions and view i got error like

```
undefined local variable or method `contacts_save_contact_path' for #<#<Class:0xafc9338>:0xb5467fc>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found myself having to put `refinery.route_path` with refinery url helpers, so in your case, `refinery.contacts_save_contact_path` might do the trick

Answer (score 3):

You have to gain access to url_helpers of your actual app and it depends on the app's namespace. For example:

In config/routes.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :foos

  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at => '/'
end
```

And `rake routes` shows:

```
    foos GET /foos(.:format) foos#index
refinery     /               Refinery::Core::Engine
```

You should be able to use:

`MyApp::Application.routes.url_helpers.foos_path`

Answer (score 1):

the path have to be someone like this: Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers.your_object_admin_your_object_path

Answer (score 0):

`main_app.contacts_save_contact_path` should work.