# refinerycms engine i18n route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

need to have multiple language.

configured i18n.rb:

```
Refinery::I18n.configure do |config|
  config.enabled = true
  config.default_locale = :en
  config.current_locale = :en
  config.default_frontend_locale = :en
  config.frontend_locales = [:en, :ru]
  config.locales = {:en=>"English", :ru=>"Russian"}
end
```

generated engine in refinerycms:

`rails generate refinery:engine product title:string description:text image:image --i18n title description`

`rails generate refinery:products`

I'm getting the following error: `No route matches {:locale=>:en, :controller=>"refinery/products/products", :action=>"show", :id=>"1"}` when I try to open any page of engine

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

After I added a custom engine to my CMS, I was having the same issue; my 'locale selector' in my application layout file caused the error you described:

```
-# Haml:
%ul.locales
  - locales.each do |locale|
    %li= link_to Refinery::I18n.locales[locale], url_for(:locale => locale), :title => Refinery::I18n.locales[locale], :class => "flags-#{locale}"
```

By changing `url_for` into `refinery.url_for` this solved the problem:

```
-# Haml:
%ul.locales
  - locales.each do |locale|
    %li= link_to Refinery::I18n.locales[locale], refinery.url_for(:locale => locale), :title => Refinery::I18n.locales[locale], :class => "flags-#{locale}"
```

Can't explain what happened yet, but maybe this will solve your problem.

To be honest, all credits should go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120050/refinerycms-cant-call-my-own-controller-route-actions) :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run:

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

after you did `rails generate refinery:products`?